# How to combine two dependent GraphQL queries with 'compose'?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

## Solved!

I'm trying to combine two dependent GraphQL queries.

The first one should get an ID and the second one should take that ID. I read that compose behaves like flowRight(), but no matter in what order I put the queries, if queryId is below queryDetails, queryDetail's is always skipped (as expected). No matter how I put my code together the variable is undefined.

```
import { graphql, compose } from 'react-apollo'
import gql from 'graphql-tag'

class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    console.log("Where's my data?")
    console.log(props)
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div />
    )
  }
}

export const queryIdConst = gql`
  query IdQuery {
    account(name:"SuperAccount") 
    {
      lists {
        edges {
          id
        }
      }
    } 
  }
`

export const queryDataConst = gql`
  query DataQuery($id: ID!) {
    account(name:"SuperAccount") 
    {
      list(id: $id) {
        displayTitle
      }
    } 
  }
`

export default compose(
  graphql(queryIdConst, {
    name: 'listId',
  }),
  graphql(queryDataConst, { 
    name: 'data',
    skip: ({ listId }) => !listId.data,
    options: ({ listId }) => ({
      variables: {
        id: list.data.account.lists.edges[0].id
      }
    })
  })
)(Home)
```

I have already tried to change the compose functions order, but anyway this is not working, as I expected it to work.

Thanks for any help!

Edit: Switched the two graphql() in compose() to be inline with [AbsoluteSith's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1967674/absolutesith) comment [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48880071/use-result-for-first-query-in-second-query-with-apollo-client)

## Solution

With hints and help from [Daniel Rearden](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6024220/daniel-rearden) and [AbsoluteSith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1967674/absolutesith) I implemented the following solution:

Changed the compose():

```
export default compose(
  graphql(queryIdConst, {
    name: 'listId',
  }),
  graphql(queryDataConst, { 
    name: 'dataHome', // changed to 'dataHome' to avoid confusion
    skip: ({ listId }) => !listId.account,
    options: ({ listId }) => ({
      variables: {
        id: listId.account.lists.edges[0].id
      }
    })
  })
)(Home)
```

And my render():

```
return(
  <div>
    { dataHome && !dataHome.loading && 
      <div>{dataHome.account.list.displayTitle}</div> 
    }
  </div>
)
```

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48880071/use-result-for-first-query-in-second-query-with-apollo-client) solution

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Yes, that's where I came from. But my variables in the second Query are always undefined. I get the query object with all the functions, but data is undefined.

In your link the variable is defined with 'firstQuery.data.someQuery.someValue', should I 'call' a query or is 'list.data.account.lists.edges[0].id' the right to access data?

Comment: Yeah try passing the right data ie; list.data.account.lists.edges[0].id. See the network calls made check if both the queries are executed and their order. But a better solution is to create a separate component for the second query

Comment: Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45511335/react-apollo-dont-run-query-on-component-load) might help too. Effectively you might not be accessing the data in the correct format/ hierarchy.

Comment: Sorry saw your schema so you should be accessing the data as listId.account.lists.edges[0].id  && check for listId value only

Comment: Thanks for your help! Yes, I was a little bit confused by renaming and accessing and the lifecycle of the query and components.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using the `graphql` HOC, by default, the wrapped component receives a prop called `data` (or `mutate` if passing in a mutation). Given a query like

```
query IdQuery {
  account(name:"SuperAccount") {
    lists {
      edges {
        id
      }
    }
  } 
}
```

once the query loads, the query result is available under `this.props.data.account`. When you use the `name` configuration option, you're telling the HOC to use something other than `data` for the prop name. So if you set name to `listId`, then your query result will be available at

```
this.props.listId.account
```

That means the second HOC inside of compose should look more like this:

```
graphql(queryDataConst, { 
  skip: ({ listId }) => !listId.account, // <--
  options: ({ listId }) => ({
    variables: {
      id: listId.account.lists.edges[0].id // <--
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for your help! 
I think I was confused with renaming and accessing afterwards. The second caveat was, that I thought the 2nd query should be listed as the 1st within my compose function, because the Doc states that it's called as flowRight(), but the 1st query must be above the 2nd, otherwise the 2nd doesn't know the 'listId'. confusion...

Anyway, that's great and it is working now!